# Way to use NHibernate to get field length limits easily

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I need to limit the input length of some of my text boxes. I'd like to link them to whatever the database length limit is in case the DBA decides to increase the max length directly in the database.

Anyone have any clue on how this is done?

Answer (score 2):

**Have a look at NHibernate.Validator.**

This system allows you to add restrictions to your entities, via attributes or XML. This information can then later on retrieved and used in your interface.

Some reading material:

- http://www.pnpguidance.net/post/nhibernatevalidatortutorialvalidatebusinessobjectsmvc.aspx
- http://nhibernate.info/doc/validator/nhibernate-validator-1-0-0-documentation.html
- http://nhibernate.info/blog/2009/05/17/nhibernate-validator-quickstart.html

Comment: thanks, i'll read those when I get a chance. I'm overwhelmed with stuff to do!

Comment: This could have been a great answer, but unfortunately the links have stopped working, so it's impossible to know now.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. Changed the links.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is possible using NHibernate. As far as I'm aware, NHibernate can be used to create the database, but it can't read table properties from the database. In other words, it will **assume** that the tables are set up the way you declared them in the mappings, and then complain if something went wrong.

As Pieter has already said, you can use **NHibernate Validator** to enforce constraints on your model. You would still need to manually change the constraints if the underlying DB changes though.

Comment: not what i want to hear, but if you're right at least you'll save me the trouble of looking for hours for a solution that doesn't exist!

Answer (score 2):

Use a [T4 template](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/T4TextTemplateTransformationToolkitCodeGenerationBestKeptVisualStudioSecret.aspx) to read the length from table schema and automatically inject into the mapping or an NHibernate Validator.

It is a little bit of work, but if you're worried about the DBA changing the schema often, this is the way to go.

Alternatively, if that's too much work, it is possible to write unit tests that compare the length in the schema to the length on the mapping. These will break if the DBA updates the schema but the mapping is not updated properly. Then, when your unit tests break you know to change the code.

Comment: it might be less work to just tell the dba not to meddle with the lengths. I'll give it a read though. Thank you!